# Why won't text wrap around images in my WP pages

Tags: html, wordpress, image

I'm creating a website in WordPress, it's going well, but whenever I try to add pictures to the page of the site, the text won't wrap around them.  The pages are supposed to be created when you're inside of your WP account, so there is minimal coding involved, and each page has it's own coding and formatting as far as html is concerned.  I would be willing to change the CSS to fix this problem, but I wouldn't know where to start.  Here is the code for the About Us page:

```html
Cougar Electric Car Company is made up of students at

<a href="http://www.kenn.cr.k12.ia.us/" target="">Kennedy High School</a> in Cedar Rapids, Iowa. Students work in teams to design and construct safe, energy-efficient electric one-person vehicles that they showcase during a series of rallies across the
Midwest. This is hands-on education. Team members apply what they’ve learned in math science, and or vocational education – and more.

<img style="float: right;" src="http://leifsegen.com/sandbox/livia_t/electric-car/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/IMG_5139-300x225.jpg" alt="IMG_5139" width="300" height="225" />

<h6>The program is designed to challenge students to:</h6>
<ul>
  <li>Apply classroom lessons to build a one-person light electric vehicle</li>
  <li>Design and engineer the vehicle to roll safely and efficiently</li>
  <li>Use problem-solving skills</li>
  <li>Promote efforts in the community to gain support</li>
  <li>Compete against other schools to see whose vehicle performs best</li>
  <li>Document the design/build/compete process</li>
</ul>

<h6><strong>Since 1997</strong></h6>

The program was launched by two students and Kennedy teacher Barry Wilson in 1997. Since then, the program has impacted hundreds of students and sparked interest in manufacturing, engineering, automotive, alternative energy, and many more career paths.
```

[Here](http://leifsegen.com/sandbox/livia_t/electric-car/wordpress/sample-page/) is the link to my About Us page.

Comment: Because the heading that comes after the image, which should be floating up next to it, has `clear:both` set on it. That's in the rules on http://leifsegen.com/sandbox/livia_t/electric-car/wordpress/wp-content/themes/kicoe/style.css?ver=20151125-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your linked page, it looks like your img tag is within a distinct paragraph tag underneath another paragraph tag. Since paragraph tags are block elements, they stack instead of allowing inline flow.

to resolve this, you want to go to the edit post/page area, and place the media *at the start* of the paragraph you want wrapping around it (or, however many lines down you want to start the wrapping). Click the image, then select the box that looks like a box w lines wrapping around it. See my screenshot for an example[image]

You can accomplish the same thing in text mode instead of visual editor mode by placing the image tag within the same paragraph tag that the paragraph is in, then giving it a float:right / left property

Answer (score 0):

Move the image inside the `<ul>` that will solve your issue. Already tested and its working

```
<ul>
<li style="list-style: none;"><img style="float: right;" src="http://leifsegen.com/sandbox/livia_t/electric-car/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/IMG_5139-300x225.jpg" alt="IMG_5139" width="300" height="225"></li><li>Apply classroom lessons to&nbsp;build a one-person light electric vehicle</li>
<li>Design and engineer the vehicle to roll safely and efficiently</li>
<li>Use problem-solving skills</li>
<li>Promote efforts in the community to gain support</li>
<li>Compete against other schools to see whose&nbsp;vehicle performs best</li>
<li>Document the design/build/compete&nbsp;process</li>
</ul>
```